# Why concurrent read-write has different results depending on default value?

Tags: go, concurrency

Why panic stop occurring if we replace global variable with true?

```
package main

import (
    "time"
)

// If here written false, the panic is expected some times.
// But if we write true here, then panic will never happen.
// Why? 
var value = false

func main() {
    go func() { for { value = true } }()

    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    for {
        if !value {
            panic("FALSE!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a data race, the result is undefined.

Comment: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/blogs/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong.html

Answer (score 0):

It is a race condition. In such situation you need to use [WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup).
Using time sleep is dangerous as we cannot predict how go routines are executed by the scheduler.
See the following code:

```
func main() {
    var wait sync.WaitGroup
    wait.Add(1);

    go func() {
        for {
            if !value {
                value = true
                wait.Done()
            }
        }
    }()

    wait.Wait()
    //time.Sleep(time.Second)

    for {
        if !value {
            panic("FALSE!")
        }
    }
}
```